# Como suma o restar de una cifra en java

Tags: java, netbeans

espero se encuentren bien.

Me encuentro realizando un pequeño proyecto para la escuela, en un pequeño apartado de nomina necesito sumar o restar de la la cifra que se refleje en "Sueldo", como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
int sueldo, incentivo, Total;

sueldo = Integer.parseInt(txtSueldo.getText());
incentivo = Integer.parseInt(txtIncentivo.getText());

Total = sueldo+incentivo;

txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(Total));
```

Configure el botón "Total" pero solo me funciona con la suma, al momento de querer restar me manda un error.

¿Me podrían apoyar con algún código que pueda usar?

También intente usar la condicional if else, pero no doy una.

Saludos

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario, Saludos

Comment: Vale, ya vemos más de cómo lo estás intentando. Qué error te sale? Añádelo también, demás que no sabemos qué quieres restar de dónde. Le vas a restar los descuentos? Qué sale al hacer la resta?

Comment: por favor agrega los mensajes de error. Nota: las variables siempre van en minúscula en java(notación de camello creo que es, ej: **miFantansticaVariable**) no es importante esto pero es uno de los standares de java. Lo importante de esto es que que sepas diferenciar métodos estaticos, clases, varibles, etc solo con un vistazo. Por eso al ver tu código de reojo asumo que es una clase por que empieza con mayúscula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

veamos qué podemos hacer:

```
int sueldo, incentivo, Total;

sueldo = Integer.parseInt(txtSueldo.getText());
incentivo = Integer.parseInt(txtIncentivo.getText());

Total = sueldo+incentivo;

txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(Total));
```

No sé exactamente si es lo que buscas, pero pondré 3 casuísticas:

1. Que solo se rellene el campo incentivos (pero no los descuentos), por lo que solo debemos hacer la suma.
2. Que solo se rellene el campo descuentos (pero no los incentivos), por lo que debemos restar.
3. Que se rellenen los dos campos, debiendo sumar y restar.
4. Que no se rellene nada y el total será solamente el sueldo.

Para solucionar esto, podemos hacer uso de los else if, comprobando qué campos están rellenos y cuáles no.

```
    int sueldo, incentivo, Total, descuento;
    String textIncentivo  = txtIncentivo.getText(); 
    String textDescuentos = textDescuento.getText();
    
    sueldo = Integer.parseInt(txtSueldo.getText());
    Total = sueldo;

    if(!textIncentivo.getText().equals("") && textDescuentos.equals("")){
      incentivo = Integer.parseInt(txtIncentivo.getText());
      Total += incentivo;

    }else if(textIncentivo.getText().equals("") && !textDescuentos.equals(""){
      descuento = Integer.parseInt(textDescuentos.getText());
      Total -= descuento;

     }else if(!textIncentivo.getText().equals("") && !textDescuentos.equals("")){
      incentivo = Integer.parseInt(txtIncentivo.getText());
      descuento = Integer.parseInt(textDescuentos.getText());
      
      Total+=incentivo;
      Total-=descuento;

    } 
    txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(Total));
```

Con esto, con la información que has aportado, debería salirte el total, dependiendo de qué campos se rellenen. En cualquier caso, si no entrara por ninguna sentencia del else-if, como ponemos antes `Total=sueldo` simplemente se mostraría el sueldo, sin descuentos y sin incentivos.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: te di la fecha para arriba buena explicacion :)

Comment: compruebas demasidas variantes, si incentivo tiene valor lo sumas al total y si descuento tiene valor lo restas al total. no necesitas comparar todas las variantes, no son dependientes incentivo y descuento

Comment: Simplemente quería mostrar de manera didáctica el por qué de mi planteamiento. Lo bueno de la programación es que lo mismo se puede hacer de mil maneras diferentes. Tu manera es también muy correcta!

Comment: Me sirvió mucho tu respuesta, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Supongo que quieras que si no escriban nada en los incentivos no sume nada y si no escriben nada en los descuentos no reste.

Entonces solo tienes que comprobar si hay algo escrito y añadirlo a la variable correspondiente, sumar incentivos y restar descuentos al sueldo.

De esta forma se abarcan todas las posibilidades.

Inicializando las variables en 0 aseguras que va a tener valor cuando hagas la operacion para calcular `total`

```
int sueldo, incentivo, descuento, Total;

incentivo = 0;
descuento = 0;

sueldo = Integer.parseInt(txtSueldo.getText());
if(!txtIncentivo.getText().equals("")){
  incentivo = Integer.parseInt(txtIncentivo.getText());
}
if(!txtDescuento.getText().equals("")){
  descuento = Integer.parseInt(txtDescuento.getText());
}

Total = sueldo+incentivo-descuento;

txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(Total));
```

Comment: La respuesta está mal. Las comprobaciones `getText().equals('')` siempre van a ser falsas, por lo que siempre se va a intentar realizar la conversión a número que fallará, resultando en una excepción de formato de entero.

Comment: Además de que las comillas tienen que ser ser dobles, las simples en tipos de datos String no funcionan.

Comment: gracias, no me.habia fijado que las comillas estaban simples @mrgold92

Comment: @EequiisVazquez Las comprobaciones de `getText().equals("")` sera falsa cuando el campo tenga algo escrito y como está negado `!` cuando tenga algo escrito entrará a la condición y convertirá a número.

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba si tienes texto dentro del campo, si no, toma ese valor como 0.

```
int sueldo, incentivo, total;

if (txtSueldo.getText() == null || txtSueldo.getText().equals("")) sueldo = 0;
else sueldo = Integer.parseInt(txtSueldo.getText());

if (txtIncentivo.getText() == null || txtIncentivo.getText().equals("")) incentivo = 0;
else incentivo = Integer.parseInt(txtIncentivo.getText());

total = sueldo + incentivo;

txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

Si además encierras la llamada a este método, o por lo menos las llamadas a `parseInt` en un bloque `try-catch`, puedes manejar los casos en que el usuario haya introducido una cadena que no es un número, para mostrar un mensaje de error.

```
calculoDelTotal() {
    // Omito el código porque es el de antes
}

// ...

botonTotal.AddActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            calculoDelTotal();
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(/* Tu mensaje de error */);
        }
    }
});
```

Incluso si te pones más purista puedes delegar en otro objeto los cálculos, para empezar a separar lógica de vista. Añado un ejemplo incluyendo los descuentos.

```
public final class Formula {
    private Formula() { }    // Clase "estática"
    public static int calcularTotal(int sueldo, int incentivo, int descuento) {
        return sueldo + incentivo - descuento;
    }
}

// ...

public class Vista {

    // Atributos, constructores y otros métodos

    private void initializeComponent() {
        botonTotal.AddActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int sueldo, incentivo, descuento;
                try {
                    if (txtSueldo.getText() == null || txtSueldo.getText().equals("")) sueldo = 0;
                    else sueldo = Integer.parseInt(txtSueldo.getText());

                    if (txtIncentivo.getText() == null || txtIncentivo.getText().equals("")) incentivo = 0;
                    else incentivo = Integer.parseInt(txtIncentivo.getText());

                    if (txtDescuento.getText() == null || txtDescuento.getText().equals("")) descuento = 0;
                    else descuento = Integer.parseInt(txtDescuento.getText());

                    txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(Formula.calcularTotal(sueldo, incentivo, descuento)));
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(/* Tu mensaje de error */);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```